# How to isolate ourself from broken API and library calls

Tags: c++, c++03

The situation is we have many API's and libraries that we reply on. When an issue occurs with one of them it's very difficult to track down. **What I want to know; is there a way we can isolate the external calls better?**

What we want: impose our own timeout on a external calls, Isolation from a crash in the call, and a transaction logger that identifies when external call logs begin and end.

**I have two possible solution:**

1. Create a thread pool to call these external API's
2. create a separate process to call all the needed API (seems too much for the number of calls.)

**Is there an obvious solution or pattern I'm missing?**

Comment: If you want to isolate completely from crashes then a separate process is definitely the way to go. If the library is within your process you can catch exceptions it might throw but you can't undo any damage it has done to your process's memory

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I think your right and I'm going to try an isolate as much as I can in a helper process.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you should be doing your best to to fix these bugs, not just try to live with them.  Have you considered using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?  That should help you pin them down.  Then you might be able to fix them (or work around them, or report them to your library vendor, or whatever)?

Comment: That's a solid point. However, there exist a point in which that is not practical. The libraries are stable today but they do change weekly, I want to isolate myself from the changes for that reason. I want to bound this problem to how to solve this technique issue first.

Comment: PS: I will explore tools, but the system is so old that they do not support most modern tools.

Comment: `The libraries ... change weekly` That's most unusual.  What's the story there?  Do you have any control over that process?

Comment: No control, it's just a big company that stared in the 80's with a "massive" code base before best practices as we know them.

Comment: Well, if I were in your shoes, I would seek to exert some control.  Don't just put up with what sounds like an impossible situation here.  Make your discomfort known and ask the people supplying your libraries to make their releases on a more sensible schedule and to test them properly.  That's more likely to move things forward, longer term, than trying to code your way round this problem.